# Replace all occurrences of a string in JSON object regardless of key

Tags: python

I have a JSON object in Python created through requests built in .json() function.

Here is a simplified sample of what I'm doing:

```
data = session.get(url)

obj = data.json()

s3object = s3.Object(s3_bucket, output_file)
s3object.put(Body=(bytes(json.dumps(obj).encode('UTF-8'))))
```

Example obj:

```
{'id': 'fab779b7-2586-4895-9f3b-c9518f34e028', 'project_id': 'a1a73e68-9943-4584-9d59-cc84a0d3e92b', 'created_at': '2017-10-23 02:57:03 -0700', 'sections': [{'section_name': '', 'items': [{'id': 'ffadc652-dd36-4b9f-817c-6539a4b462ab', 'created_at': '2017-10-23 03:36:13 -0700', 'updated_at': '2017-10-23 03:38:32 -0700', 'created_by': 'paul', 'question_text': 'Drawing Ref(s)', 'spec_ref': '', 'display_number': null, 'response': '', 'comment': 'see attached mh309', 'position': 1, 'is_conforming': 'N/A', 'display_type': 'text'}]}]}
```

I need to replace any occurrence of the string "N/A" with "Not Applicable" anywhere it appears regardless of its key or location before I upload the JSON to S3. I cannot use local disk writes hence the reason this is done this way.

Is this possible?

My original plan was to turn it to a string and just replace before turning back, is this inefficient?

Thanks,

Comment: Please show us how your `obj` looks like It might be a dictionary as well

Comment: The obj can change depending on what URL is passed to it. I'll add an example one to the post.

Comment: Is `obj` a string?

Comment: No. Its a dict. But I've just added I was planning to turn it to a string then back. But would that be inefficient as I need to run this a few thousand times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `obj` is a dict. One way to replace `N/A` with `Not Applicable` regardless of location is to convert it to a string, use `string.replace` and convert it back to dict for further processing

```
import json

#Original dict with N/A
obj = {'id': 'fab779b7-2586-4895-9f3b-c9518f34e028', 'project_id': 'a1a73e68-9943-4584-9d59-cc84a0d3e92b', 'created_at': '2017-10-23 02:57:03 -0700', 'sections': [{'section_name': '', 'items': [{'id': 'ffadc652-dd36-4b9f-817c-6539a4b462ab', 'created_at': '2017-10-23 03:36:13 -0700', 'updated_at': '2017-10-23 03:38:32 -0700', 'created_by': 'paul', 'question_text': 'Drawing Ref(s)', 'spec_ref': '', 'display_number': None, 'response': '', 'comment': 'see attached mh309', 'position': 1, 'is_conforming': 'N/A', 'display_type': 'text'}]}]}

#Convert to string and replace
obj_str = json.dumps(obj).replace('N/A', 'Not Applicable')

#Get obj back with replacement
obj = json.loads(obj_str)
```

Comment: @ck3mp This is a hacky solution and it will probably work for you most of the time...until one time when `"N/A"` happens to appear as a substring somewhere else where it will fail silently and break your code. The solution by [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56395427/5858851) is the correct way to do this.

Comment: fair point @pault ! wondering if I can change it by adding a recursive iteration and replacing values where 'N/A' is found?

Comment: Couldn't this _hacky_ code be made more robust by adding quotes in the "old" and "new" replacement strings ? My interpretation of the original question is that partial matches should not be replaced, so wouldn't `json.dumps(obj).replace('"N/A"', '"Not Applicable"')` just work ? Or, going further and to prevent matching keys instead of values : `json.dumps(obj).replace(': "N/A"', ': "Not Applicable"')`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the Object you've pasted here must be of dict type, you can check it as if "`type(json_object)` is class dict". With that assumption youcan do it as:-

```
keys = json_object.keys()
for i in keys:
    if json_object[i]=="N/A":
        json_object[i]="Not Available"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The recommended way to do type checking in Python is to use the built-in [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function — in this case it would be: `isinstance(json_object, dict)`.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Devesh Kumar Singh's answer works with the sample json data in your question, converting the whole thing to a string, and then doing a wholesale bulk replace of the substring seems possibly error-prone because potentially  it might change it in portions other than only in the values associated with dictionary keys.

To avoid that I would suggest using the following, which is more selective even though it takes a few more lines of code:

```
import json

def replace_NA(obj):

    def decode_dict(a_dict):
        for key, value in a_dict.items():
            try:
                a_dict[key] = value.replace('N/A', 'Not Applicable')
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return a_dict

    return json.loads(json.dumps(obj), object_hook=decode_dict)


obj = {'id': 'fab779b7-2586-4895-9f3b-c9518f34e028', 'project_id': 'a1a73e68-9943-4584-9d59-cc84a0d3e92b', 'created_at': '2017-10-23 02:57:03 -0700', 'sections': [{'section_name': '', 'items': [{'id': 'ffadc652-dd36-4b9f-817c-6539a4b462ab', 'created_at': '2017-10-23 03:36:13 -0700', 'updated_at': '2017-10-23 03:38:32 -0700', 'created_by': 'paul', 'question_text': 'Drawing Ref(s)', 'spec_ref': '', 'display_number': None, 'response': '', 'comment': 'see attached mh309', 'position': 1, 'is_conforming': 'N/A', 'display_type': 'text'}]}]}
obj = replace_NA(obj)
```